# jQuery - Safari - Mac OS - click() event not working when clicked once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.open-close-objects').click(function(){
         console.log('clicked');
     }); 
});
```

I have this code in on my website, it works everywhere apart from Safari. I have to click sometimes twice and sometimes triple-click for it to trigger.

We are experiencing problems with multiple machines.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,
David

PS. Apologies if it has been asked before.

Comment: Please post the Safari version(s) this is occurring with that you have noticed.

Comment: Also, does switching to `$('body').on('click','.open-close-objects',function(){` instead, make any sort of difference with your test cases?

Comment: Lastly, please let us know which jquery include you are using (which version, if using a remote source, or local copy).

Comment: Safari version 13.1.1, jQuery version 3.1.1 local copy

Comment: switching it to bind the event on the body does not work as well, the same takes two or three clicks before registered.

Comment: This is very weird. I'm using Safari (13.1.1) in our admin tools (tons of click handlers with jquery), which is why I found this question concerning. However I'm not getting this behavior. We use both 10.14, and 10.15 (latest updates).